# Choose a kernel for next system boot

Tags: python, kernel

I have been testing a number of kernel builds and I decide to have a go at writing some Python code. The idea is to select which kernel to boot on the next reboot. I could have done it in Bash but fancied a new experience, hence I had a go at Python.

I've been testing under bash under Linux(Debian)

Would love some feedback:

Summary:

- Read the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file
- Extract the kernel names
- Present a simple menu
- Select the kernel
- Exit, printing the `grub-reboot` command (not executed)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Read a grub.cfg file and parse the entries
import re
from simple_term_menu import TerminalMenu

# Get current kernels from grub.cfg in correct format
def get_kernels(menu_items):
    majorcount=0
    mincount=0
    with open('/boot/grub/grub.cfg',mode='r') as file:
        for line in file:
            # Check if line will contains either the string 'menu' or 'submenu'
            if re.match(r'^menu',line) or re.match(r'^submenu',line):
                try:
                    # Find the menu string between single quotes
                    entry = re.search('\'(.+?)\'', line).group(1)
                    menu_items.append('{} - {}'.format(majorcount,entry))
                    majorcount += 1

                except:
                    continue
            # Check to see if the line begins with <TAB>menu if so looks like a submenu entry
            elif re.match(r'\tmenu',line):
                entry = re.search('\'(.+?)\'', line).group(1)
                menu_items.append('{}>{} - {}'.format(majorcount,mincount,entry))
                mincount +=1
        #
        # Before we return add an Exit to the end of the menu
        majorcount += 1
        menu_items.append('{} - Exit'.format(majorcount))

        return
#########
#
# Print a simple Menu on the screen
def print_menu(menu_items):
    cli_menu_title=' Grub Kernel Selection \n'
    cli_menu=TerminalMenu(menu_items,title=cli_menu_title,clear_screen=True,
                          clear_menu_on_exit=False)
    menu_index=cli_menu.show()

    return menu_index
#########
def main():

    menu_items=[]
    get_kernels(menu_items)
    index=print_menu(menu_items)
    #
    # Now extract the string to pass to 'grub-reboot'. If 'Exit' choosen then just end
    # As 'Exit' will be the last entry if the index == the length of menu_items then assume 'Exit'
    # NB index starts at zero so will never match the length of menu_items, so increment it first
    if (index + 1) != len(menu_items):
        print(' grub-reboot {}'.format(re.match("(.*?) ",menu_items[index]).group()))
    else:
        print('Exiting not kernel selected..')
#########
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```